# Closing a database using VBA code from a seperate database

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to close one Access database (let's call it Database A) via VBA code from another Database (Database B).

In the example here, if Database A is open when Database B launches, I would want Database A to close. Is this possible using VBA?

I've had a google about, but all answers seem to be related to closing the current database using VBA, which of course I could achieve with DoCmd.Quit.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the databases linked at all?

Comment: No - not the sense of having any linked tables etc. They both perform different aspects of the same function, so thematically linked!

Comment: @HansUP - Yes - see explanation below re clones etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hijack it:

```
Dim OtherDB As Object

sOther = "Z:\Documents\other.accdb"
Set OtherDB = GetObject(sOther)
OtherDB.Application.Quit
```

It may make life difficult for someone.

Comment: Hello again, Remou! Thanks, will try that and report back - it shouldn't cause any problem, as the database to be closed is only temporary: the function of Database B is to delete Database A.

Comment: @OliJeffery This may be off topic but why is Database B's only function to delete Database A? Also did you mean close and not delete?

Comment: We have a database with multiple (over 300) users. I split the database to stop corruption. Traditionally, I would then give all users their own copy of the front end of the database. However, we access all our programs through Citrix rather than our local machines, so this isn't possible. What I've instead done is to create a launcher that produces an ad-hoc clone of the front end whenever someone logs in, so everyone is working from a different front end, preventing corruption. The function of Database B is to delete the clone (A) once logged out so we don't have a trail of unused clones.

Comment: @Tony318 - To answer your question more precisely, Database B is meant to delete Database A, but first it has to close Database A or the Kill function doesn't work; it has to come from Database B rather than just a DoCmd.Quit on Database A because A launches B, which runs the code on opening, often before the DoCmd.Quit has kicked in from A.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but maybe this will help someone.  I had a database in which I used VBA to open another db and run a macro.  I wanted to then close the db.  The code which worked for me is below, it includes the entire process from open to close.

```
Function functionName()

Static acc As Access.Application
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dbname As String
dbname = "absolutePathToDBHere.accdb"
Set acc = New Access.Application
acc.Visible = True
Set db = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbname, False, False)
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase dbname
acc.DoCmd.RunMacro ("macroName")
acc.DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll

db.Close
Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hello Sir Im noob but it works on me.

```
Application.CurrentDb.Close
Application.FollowHyperlink (CurrentProject.Path & "\MyNewDB.accdb")
DoCmd.Quit acQuitPrompt  'i dont know why its closed my previous Database
```

Thanks. Forgive me if i am wrong.